# How to inject session bean into a POJO using Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ejb

I am having a EJB 3.0 Session Bean which implements the Local interface, and I have a pure POJO also.

How can I inject a Session Bean into the POJO rather than manual JNDI look up in to POJO through spring(using `@Resource` and `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor`)?.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

To inject an EJB3 into a POJO (which is possible [since Spring 2.5](http://www.infoq.com/articles/spring-2.5-part-1)), I think that you should use `@EJB` instead of `@Resource`. Quoting [Spring EJB and JPA](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/spring-ejb-and-jpa.html) (read it all, it has many examples):

> Don't forget to add:
>
> ```
> <context:annotation-config/>
> ```
>
> It allows various annotations to be detected in bean classes: Spring's `@Required` and `@Autowired`, as well as JSR 250's `@PostConstruct`, `@PreDestroy` and `@Resource` (if available), JAX-WS's `@WebServiceRef` (if available), EJB3's `@EJB` (if available), and JPA's `@PersistenceContext` and `@PersistenceUnit` (if available). Alternatively, you may choose to activate the individual BeanPostProcessors for those annotations.

Also have a look at [Spring support for @EJB annotations: example?](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=50232) on the Spring forums.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the poetically-named [`LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/ejb/access/LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean.html), which creates a spring bean proxy pointing at the session EJB on JNDI. You can then wire this proxy into your POJO using the usual Spring wiring techniques. The proxy bean will implement the same local interface of your EJB.

See [this section of the Spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/ejb.html#ejb-access-local) for an example.